# Ubuntu Vm on Ubuntu Host

Tags: virtualbox, lts

I have been running an Ubuntu VM on Virtualbox with no issues.

today when I tried to log on the VM seems to start fine and the Ubuntu icon flashes at the bottom of the screen then it just go to a blank/black screen with a cursor underscore.

does absolutely nothing after that. I've tried every combo of changing the display settings in Virtualbox and disables 3d acceleration. nothing seems to work.

I've even tried to create a new VM and point to the VDI but this has the same result.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the VM (or the host) running 12.04 like you’ve tagged? One option would be to boot the VM with an installation .iso mounted. You can boot into a Live Session then check the logs for any errors that might be preventing the machine from booting 

Comment: Sorry both host and VM running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS